# using a coldfusion variable in a javascript function name

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I have a function in a `.cfm` template that gets called multiple times in another page. The problem is, I need the functions name to be dynamic. Is there a way to concatenate a ColdFusion variable with a javascript function name? Like so:

**CFML:**

```
<cfset id = "">
```

**JS:**

```
function name#id# ()
```

Comment: Yes but it's not likely necessary to duplicate the entire function. You can probably pass the id as an argument. You should provide examples of the calls to the funtion as well as the function itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  <cfoutput>
    function name#id#()
  </cfoutput>
</script>
```

But it is more likely that you want to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  <cfoutput>
     name(#id#)
  </cfoutput>
</script>
```